# Entity framework - VB .net, insert entries into child table before saving changes to parent table

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 using VB Express 2010 and SQL Server 2008 express. I have setup EDM. I have two tables 1. Trans_Details which is parent and 2. Trans_Details_Split which is child table .These are linked with PK and FK relationship in database with trans_id column.

I have a form having datagridview which is bound to parent table (trans_details). User is allowed to save only 1 row in this datagridview at a time. This datagridview has a button called "Split". When user wants to enter various child entries for the parent transaction row, they click on Split button (even before saving this parent transaction row). It opens up another form which has a datagridview bound to child table trans_details_split.

Business case says that once the user enters details of child recods and closes child form, the focus will come back to parent row. User will then click on Save button on this parent form. At this time, the application should insert the records for parent and child forms/tables together.

I searched through internet but could not figure out the way to do it. I am sure this must be very common requirement, but I am feeling lost.

Could anyone help me in this regard?

ps: Since these are different forms I am having difficulty in passing the information from child to parent (or vice versa). If both were in the same form, I think I know how to go about.

Thanks in advance

--Prasad

Comment: Your business case specifies that the child and parent rows are saved at the same time, not child-first.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes, you are right...Thanks for pointing this...